# Determine the acceleration and angular acceleration of a disc

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The question is:

> A 90kg disc is floating in a frictionless vacuum. A 150N force is
>   applied to the outer rim of the disc. The disc has a radius of 0.25m
>   and a radius of gyration of 0.16m. What is the acceleration and
>   angular acceleration of this disc?

To solve it I set up these equations:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{a} = \mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{a}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{\alpha} = \frac{\mathbf{I}\times\mathbf{\alpha}}{0.25}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{a}+\mathbf{F}_{\alpha} = 150 N\tag{3}
\end{equation}

You can find I and plug it in along with m, but that still leaves 4 unknowns and only 3 equations. I need a 4th equation but I'm not sure what else is known about the problem.

Comment: Did you use $I = m \rho^2$, where $\rho=0.16\,{\rm m}$ in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's important to properly understand the equations of rotational motion. Rather than $F = ma,$ the operative equation of motion is $\tau = I \alpha$, where $\tau$ is the [torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque), $I$ is the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) and $\alpha$ is the [angular acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration). This problem also requires you to know the definition of the radius of gyration in the form of $r_g \equiv \sqrt\frac{I}{m}$. With a proper understanding of the definitions of $\tau$ and $\alpha$, you then have all the information that you need to solve the problem.

EDIT: The above answer referred solely to the rotational acceleration of the disk. The translational acceleration of the center of mass of the disk must be worked out separately using $F = ma$.

Comment: Could you be a little less vague? I believe I understand T = Iα. I rewrote the torque as a force applied to the rim of the disc, so that I could make the equation Fa + Fα = 150N. In this equation, Fα represents the force that is generating the torque. 

`T = αI

Fα = T / r

Fα = αI / r`

Comment: I am focusing on the definitions of the quantities in the equation $\tau = I \alpha$ because you seem to be treating torque as a quantity with the same units as force, which is not correct. Also, since this problem is solely concerned with rotational motion, the equation $F = ma$ (which applies to translational motion) is not used at all.

Comment: It is not solely concerned with rotational motion, the disc is not anchored at the center point. A portion of the force will cause angular acceleration and a portion will cause translational acceleration.

Comment: I stand corrected regarding the presence of translational motion. However, you still need to decouple the rotational and translational motions. That is, you can solve for the rotational motion without any reference to the $F = ma$ law for the translational motion. And, as I said before, you need to make sure you are using the correct units for torques. They are not the same as forces.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't realize it was as simple as calculating the two values separately. For some reason I thought the force had to be 'shared' between the translation and the rotation.

Comment: You are welcome. The combination of rotational and translational motion can indeed be difficult to understand at first. As you now see, the force applied to the rim does two things: it applies a torque proportional to the radius of the disc, and it provides translational acceleration to the center of mass of the disc (assuming the disk is a rigid body). And I hope it is now clear that since force and torque have different units, you cannot add them together in an equation.

Comment: You know the equation of motion for rotation is $\tau = I \alpha + \omega \times I \omega$, but when the direction of rotation is along a principal axis of $I$ then the last part cancels out.

Comment: I stumbled upon this when I was looking to solve a more generalized problem. It seems unintuitive to me that if the force is acting at the rim you get linear acceleration and angular acceleration. But if the same force acts on the center of mass you get the same linear acceleration but no angular acceleration. This makes it seem like you get the angular acceleration "for free". Surely there is a flaw in my logic and I would appreciate if you could point it out.

Comment: My question about "free" angular acceleration is answered in section 5.5 of [this paper on unconstrained rigid body dynamics](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf). The paper confirms kleingordon's answer for the original questions and helps me with my more general question.

Comment: @DanielKoverman I am glad you have found your answer! That link is a useful supplement to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is only *one* force applied to the system $F = 150\,{\rm N}$ not two, $F_a$ and $F_\alpha$.

Then you have

1. The total force applied equals the mass times the acceleration of the center of gravity.
2. The total torque applied equals the mass moment of inertia (at the center of gravity) times the angular acceleration plus the gyroscopic forces (which are zero in your case).

So what is the torque applied when $F$ is located at the edge of the disk?
What is the mass moment of inertia of disk of mass $m$ with radius of gyration $\rho$?

Once you answer the above questions you can proceed to solve your problem.